# How to convert a double data rate (DDR, DTR) signal in a single data rate (STR) signal?

Tags: bus

Is there a simple way (simple hardware) to convert a DDR signal to STR signal?

Example:

8 bit DDR bus at 25 MHz to 8 bit STR bus at 50 MHz.

For LCD communication at 1.8V or 3.3V.